# What is the ideal of the boundary of the first quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the boundary of the first quadrant in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $S_1 = \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x \in [0, \infty)\}$ and $S_2 = \{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \in [0, \infty)\}$.

What is the ideal of $S_1$? That is, what is $I(S_1)$ ?

The definition of an ideal of a set is:

$I(S) = \{f \in k[x_1, \cdots, x_n] \mid f(a) = 0, \; \forall a \in S\}$, where $k$ is a field.

So the ideal of $S_1$ is the collection of polynomials which vanish on $S_1$. Since we are in 2D, aren't there infinitely many of them?

Comment: Thanks. Then for $S_1$ it is: $\langle y \rangle $

Answer (score 0):

From @Sassatelli Giulio's comment, the ideals are the boundary $\langle y \rangle$ for the x-axis and $\langle x \rangle$ for the y-axis.